# Xdebug 3 has no effect on YAF framework breakpoints

Tags: php, xdebug, yaf

In `$test = time();`, there is no effect at the direct breakpoint. You need to break at `$application->run()` and then step into the effect. Why?

I expect the breakpoints directly on the Controller to work; I have no problem using other frameworks like Laravel.

index.php

```php
$application->bootstrap();
$application->run();
```

Test.php

```php
class TestController extends Yaf_Controller_Abstract
{
    public function indexAction($name = "Stranger") {
        $test = time();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be no difference. Works for me in my custom "framework" or even 8-10 years old simple projects. Quite likely you are doing something different. 1) Is it as CLI and web page debug? 2) How do you debug it. 3) Maybe that code is not executed at all (e.g. wrong route or file used). 4) Or perhaps you are seeing the cached results? 5) What Xdebug log says about it -- is the file and line numbers are correct when breakpoint is set? It's hard to guess what might be wrong with this little info.